# How to escape strings for use as XML value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-drive

Is there an official function for escaping text to be used as value in XML, in Google Sheets (in Google Drive/Google Docs)?

Ie a text like

```
Mytext<hello
```

Should be output like

```
Mytext&lt;hello
```

If not, is there a best practice regex replace around?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a custom function:

```
function xmlescape(text) {
    return text.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
               .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
               .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
               .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
               .replace(/'/g, '&apos;');
}
```

I hope I didn't forget something.

Comment: I don't think this handles the escaping of unicode characters